# Return value for method from closure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

Is there a way that I can return value for `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method from my closure? Or should I do it differently?

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    getDataFromSomewhere() { succeeded, data in
        if succeeded {
            // Should return true here            
        } else {
            self.errorAlert("Error", message: "Can't get data...")
            // Should return false here
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` return from the point where you put `// Should return true here`.  You need to do something like this instead:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    var returnValue: Bool = false

    getDataFromSomewhere() { succeeded, data in
        if succeeded {
            returnValue = true
        } else {
            self.errorAlert("Error", message: "Can't get data...")
            returnValue = false
        }
    }

    return returnValue
}
```

Note that this will only work if `getDataFromSomewhere` executes the closure before `getDataFromSomewhere` returns. If `getDataFromSomewhere` stores the closure, and arranges for it to be called later on (after an asynchronous network request, for example), then this won't work. It will just make `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` return the value you used to initialize `returnValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this method to sync by using dispatch group mechanism.

```
  let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

      override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
             var returnValue: Bool = false
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                getDataFromSomewhere() { succeeded, data in
                    if succeeded {
                       returnValue = true     
                    } else {
                        self.errorAlert("Error", message: "Can't get data...")
                        returnValue = false
                    }
                    self.dispatchGroup.leave() 
                }
            }
            
            dispatchGroup.wait()
    
            return returnValue
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

if your getDataFromSomewhere closure is async after then you have no other solution than using completion handlers.

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?, , completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {
    getDataFromSomewhere() { succeeded, data in
        if succeeded {
            completion(true)
        } else {
            self.errorAlert("Error", message: "Can't get data...")
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` is a an override, so changing its signature will prevent the system calling it.

Comment: ah okay I didn't notice that, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Are you opposed to using prepareforsegue and an unwind segue?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "fuelButtonUnhide"{

        if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? DateViewController {

            vc.fuelHidden = false
        }
    } 
}

@IBAction func unwindDateViewToAddFuel(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
    //Change any data from the date view here
    println("Hit done from date view")
}
```

You can pass data in the prepareforsegue and retrieve data in the unwind action.

Comment: That's not the case. I need to know can I return "methods return" from closure.